# Setup Linux backup with Bacula and Webmin

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

Hi guys I'm having troubles finding a good documentation to setup an easy and possibly web oriented backup solution for one of our CentOS 5.4 file server.

The things I need to accomplish are the following:

- find a solutions that runs possibly via web to make it easy to manage it
- find a solution that has a UI and is simple to manage
- backups are done from one linux box onto an other linux box on the same network (just different location)
- be able to understand if the BK worked out well and/or if any error happened

The reason why I need this is because it's managed primarly from my business partner which is not a programmer although he's pretty good with things like Webmin and so on...

Since he likes Webmin a lot I had a look at those two programs:

- Amanda
- Bacula

but I might be open to different solutions.

I have both of them installed but not running (including DB for Bacula) I lack directions there are a bunch of things that I don't understand first of all how to backup on the LAN disk...

Have you guys ever found a good and simple guide / tutorial on this topic? Anything would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bacula + Webmin

Looking through the [Bacula wiki](http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php) on the [3rd party addons](http://wiki.bacula.org/doku.php?id=3rd_party_addons) page I found the following:

```
Webmin puts a GUI on lots of system administration tasks and has a module for bacula.


* Bacula Backup System 1.450
* Description   Configure Bacula to perform backups and restores manually or on schedule, for one or many systems
* Download  bacula-backup.wbm.gz
* Website   http://www.webmin.com/webmin/standard.html
* Author    Jamie Cameron
* Last updated  2009-01-27 01:35:47
```

So it would appear that Bacula is a standard module included with Webmin.

#### Tutorials

I found this tutorial as a blog post titled: [Installing Bacula 5.2.6 with webmin on Centos 6.2](http://wassimzaarour.blogspot.com/2012/02/installing-bacula-526-on-centos-62.html). It should be fairly straightforward to adapt it to Ubuntu or Debian as well.

Here's 2 other tutorials. The first is titled: [Install And Configure Bacula Server In CentOS 6.4 / RHEL 6.4](http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-bacula-server-in-centos-6-4-rhel-6-4/). Looks to be similar to the first, but might have additional details that are lacking. The second one is titled: [How to: Install Bacula on Centos6 (or Fedora16)](http://www.technowut.com/2012/06/21/how-to-install-bacula-on-centos6-or-fedora16/).

It's always good to have multiple tutorials!

#### Webmin + Filesystem Backup

If your needs are modest you might be able to get by using just the stock backup facility included with Webmin. There's a tutorial titled: [Filesystem Backup](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/FilesystemBackup)that discusses your options and the different setups.

**initial webmin backup screen**
   [image: ss of webmin backup #1]

**add a new backup screen**
   [image: ss of webmin backup #2]

#### BackupPC

Another easy option to setup is [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/). Has a very nice web interface and is easy to operate.

[image: ss of backupPC]

Answer (score 0):

I personally use webacula, the web GUI for Bacula which allows one to accomplish many specific tasks, including access to the Bacula console if needed. Regarding documentation, have you looked at Bacula's website? There is good documentation and a good wiki as well.

Comment: Well I did, but it's mostly based on the CLI of Bacula and there's about nothing on managing it form Webmin. If there aren't other option i will first learn how to use bacula from command line then teach my partner how to do the same things from webmin in the simpliest posstible way. I was hoping to find a user guide about the webmin module, it might be possible that after I learn Bacula pretty well I will be able to have my partner manage it form Webmin with ease, so far not really. I'll have a look at webacula now, thanks!